# fastest c++ / stl algorithm to find strings in set of pairs

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl

I'm looking for a very fast algorithm to return the values of pairs which are stored in a set like this `set<pair<string,string>>`

To be more specific I look for all the second-values, where the first-value starts with a string.

Example:
I have a set with these pairs:

```
<"asdf","qwer">,
<"asdfghj", "qwertyui">,
<"lkj","mno">
```

Then I call my method with "asdf" an I want to get back a set or vector of these strings:

```
"qwer"
"qwertyui"
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you change your original data structure? It's not optimal for this task.

Comment: The fact that you're storing the pairs in a `std::set` implies that they will be ordered by the keys already. You could use `std::set::lower_bound()` to find the first element that has a key that is lexicographically greater than or equal to your search key, then iterate until that condition is no longer valid. A better question might be whether there is a better data structure to use.

Comment: Realistically, how large is the data set?  It makes a big difference to how you approach the problem.

Comment: the datastructure has to remain like this. there will be about 500.000 elements in this set

Comment: There is no "fastest" algorithm in general. There could be fastest algorithm for particular set of data, or there are algorithms with certain characteristics. How they will behave depends on data and your requirements (memory available etc).

Comment: How much does it have to remain like that?  If I was to change your data structure in such a way that all existing use of the data structure would give the same results, would that be acceptable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fact that you're storing the pairs in a `std::set` implies that they will be ordered by the keys already. You could use `std::set::lower_bound()` to find the first element that has a key that is lexicographically greater than or equal to your search key, then iterate until that condition is no longer valid.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.
But how does lower_bound work, if my set contains a pair<string, string>?

Comment: @Karl: The `std::set` is sorted using `operator<` by default. If you look up `operator<` for a `std::pair`, then you'll see that it sorts lexicographically based on the first element of the pair, then by the second. So your set will be sorted by the first element of the pairs, then by the second element in the event that you have entries where the first strings match.